# How in "fp-ts" HKT and Kind, Kind2, ... are matching types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, fp-ts

Following the example in this [link to HKT.ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/docs/guides/HKT.md) we have below:

```
export function lift<F extends URIS2>(F: Functor2<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => <E>(fa: Kind2<F, E, A>) => Kind2<F, E, B>
export function lift<F extends URIS>(F: Functor1<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: Kind<F, A>) => Kind<F, B>
export function lift<F>(F: Functor<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: HKT<F, A>) => HKT<F, B>
export function lift<F>(F: Functor<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: HKT<F, A>) => HKT<F, B> {
  return (f) => (fa) => F.map(fa, f)
}
```

And this works for `Identity`, `Option` and `Either` Functors perfectly:

```
const double = (n: number): number => n * 2

const doubleIdentity = lift(I.Functor)(double)
const doubleOption = lift(O.Functor)(double)
const doubleEither = lift(E.Functor)(double)
```

Why `export function lift<F>(F: Functor<F>): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (fa: HKT<F, A>) => HKT<F, B>` is the most general and fallback case. following `HKT` and `Kind`, `Kind2`, ..., the final type for each seems to not match! (consider [Option](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts) and [HKT](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/HKT.ts) definitions)

There is an article from the author of fp-ts [in this link](https://medium.com/@gcanti/higher-kinded-types-in-typescript-static-and-fantasy-land-d41c361d0dbe), but in there, the author has added all the properties in `HKT` to the `Option` but in reality in `fp-ts` hasn't done the same.

Can someone please explain how this lift function types of `Kind` `Kind2` and `HKT` are matching?